# How do I convert a column of type 'int64' to datetime?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

There is an 'x' column (int64) in which only the year and month are displayed and all days are displayed as '00'.
(Example : 19501200,19541100,19590300...)

After several attempts, I ran into a problem where all values ​​were converted to missing values.

How do I solve it?

```
df['x'] = df['x'].astype(str)
df['x'] = pd.to_datetime(df['x'], format='%Y%m%d', errors='coerce')
```

**OutPut**

> All values ​​changed to 'NaT'.

```
df['x'] = df['x'].astype(str)
df['x'] = df['x'].str[:6]
df['x'] = pd.to_datetime(df['x'], format='%Y%m', errors='coerce')
```

**Output**

> All values ​​changed to 'NaT'.

**Expected**

> Converting to a datetime in which only the year and month are displayed, such as '195012' , '195411' and '195903'.

Comment: You might want to add a hardcoded demo dataframe to not make us build our own by speculating whats in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because your format is not right, `00` is not a valid day, so to ignore that, pass directly `00` instead of `%d`, also typecasting to `str` is not necessary.

```py
df['x'] = pd.to_datetime(df['x'], format='%Y%m00', errors='coerce')

0   1950-12-01
1   1954-11-01
2   1959-03-01
Name: x, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Comment: btw it is not necessary to convert  x to string

Comment: @AnuragDabas, updated the answer accordingly

Answer (score 1):

You may use:

```
>>pd.to_datetime('19501210', yearfirst=True)
Timestamp('1950-12-10 00:00:00')
```

So simply (since you said all days are zero):

```
>>pd.to_datetime('19501200', format='%Y%m00')
Timestamp('1950-12-01 00:00:00')
```